# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to

Tags: mysql, database

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

```
create table 'spring3'.'employee'(
    id int,
    firstname varchar (32),
    lastname varchar (32),
    email varchar (32),
    phonenumber varchar (32),
    hiredate date,
    salary int
);
```

```
create table 'spring4'.'product'(
    id int,
    name varchar (32),
    quantity int,
    price float,
    available boolean
);
```

Comment: Identifiers like database names, table names and column names should be wrapped in backticks, not apostrophes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: What do you mean "Could you please answer me?", you ask like he owes you something, your very rude. The error clearly states that __You have an error in your SQL syntax__ if you don't know what that means then you didn't try researching the issue before asking about it, which Stack Overflow clearly asks you to do.

Comment: my bad sir. Please understand me sir. I am trying to be a good writer in english. Thanks JAY-DEV.

Comment: Thank you sir. I didn't know the usage of backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in the quotes mark.
Use:

```
create table `spring3`.`employee`(
id int ,
firstname varchar (32),
lastname varchar (32),
email varchar (32),
phonenumber varchar (32),
hiredate date,
salary int );
```

Keep in mind that your id should be, not null auto_increment and primary key.
So your table would be:

```
create table `spring3`.`employee`(
id int not null auto_increment ,
firstname varchar (32),
lastname varchar (32),
email varchar (32),
phonenumber varchar (32),
hiredate date,
salary int,
Primary key id(`id`) );
```